# Regular Expression to Match EXACTLY Any Number of Characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to count the number of exact consecutive occurrence of characters using ***regex***. Let the patterns be `"aa"` and `"bbb"` say, i.e. the number of times `"a"` occurs **exactly twice and consecutively**; `"b"` occurs **exactly thrice and consecutively** (they can be bounded before and after by any character including nothing except by the character itself). If the test vector is

```
c("baa", "aaaa", "aab", "aa", "bbba", "bbaabbb")
```

the result for the counts should be as follows:

[image]

The patterns matching `"aa"` being `c("baa", "aab", "aa", "bbaabbb")`   &

The patterns matching `"bbb"` being `c("bbba", "bbaabbb")`

I have used `"\\<"` & `"\\>"` but it doesn't quite give me the result I want. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Please share the code you used to test.

Comment: Do you want to absolutely use `regex` package ? Because you can do this with `stringr` package.

`vec <- c("baa", "aaaa", "aab", "aa", "bbba", "bbaabbb");`
`count_aa <- sum(str_detect(vec,'aa'))`
And so on...

Comment: @Smich, I am aware of stringr. It will fail to ignore condition where it can be bounded before and after by any character including nothing except by the character itself. Regex is the only way I think it can be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match the character "a" occuring exactly twice, you could use a negative lookbehind combined with a negative lookahead. I.e., you look for a position that

- does NOT follow a character "a",
- contains the string "aa" and
- is NOT followed by an "a"

The regex for that is `(?<!a)a{2}(?!a)`.

**Example:**

```
test <- c("baa", "aaaa", "aab", "aa", "bbba", "bbaabbb")
grep("(?<!a)a{2}(?!a)", test, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "baa"     "aab"     "aa"      "bbaabbb"
```

Matching the character "b" occuring exactly three times is done analogously:

```
grep("(?<!b)b{3}(?!b)", test, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "bbba"    "bbaabbb"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also split and get the `table`

```
 table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(v1, "(?<=b)(?=a)|(?<=a)(?=b)", perl =TRUE), 
            function(x) x[x %in% c('aa', 'bbb')])))
 # aa bbb 
 # 4   2
```

If there are other characters,

```
table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(v2, "(?<=[^a])(?=a)|(?<=a)(?!a)",
         perl = TRUE), function(x) x[x %in% c('aa', 'bbb')])))
# aa bbb 
#  5   2
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("baa", "aaaa", "aab", "aa", "bbba", "bbaabbb")
v2 <- c("baa", "aaaa", "aab", "aa", "bbba", "bbaabbb", "caa")
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the string only contains the letters "a" and "b"? This approach wouldn't match `"caa"`, would it?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to bash your answer. I think the `strsplit` is very elegant. I was just wondering if this approach would e.g. catch the `"aa"` in the string `"caa"` (*...they can be bounded before and after by **any character** including nothing except by the character itself*)

Comment: Yes Ikop it doesn't contain only a & b. Thank you Akrun for your effort, in addition, I am not sure this approach will be robust. If I want to check  length 1 all the way to 10, I will have to physically type in all the patterns I want e.g. "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", ... but with Ikop's method I can combine easily **for loop** & **length** functions to know the number of 1,2,3, ... occurrences for either a or b. Perhaps if you can make it easier to generalize and not specific.

Comment: @TundeAwosanya  Regarding your comment, `table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(v2, "(?<=[^a])(?=a)|(?<=a)(?!a)",perl = TRUE), function(x) Map(function(y, z) x[x %in% c(y, z)],  c('aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'), c('bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb')))))` can get the output you wanted